# How to turn off fakemongo logs

Tags: java, mongodb, fongo

I am using Fongo, Fongo is an in-memory java implementation of MongoDB.

How to prevent these logs It creating a lengthy log which occupies a lot of space. I am using following dependencies

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.fakemongo</groupId>
            <artifactId>fongo</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

I am getting this kind of logs

```
12:13:34.406 [TestNG-test=Package with subpackages-1] DEBUG com.mongodb.FongoDBCollection
12:13:34.406 [TestNG-test=Package with subpackages-1] DEBUG com.mongodb.FongoDBCollection
12:13:34.407 [TestNG-test=Package with subpackages-1] DEBUG com.mongodb.FongoDBCollection
12:13:34.407 [TestNG-test=Package with subpackages-1] DEBUG com.mongodb.FongoDBCollection
12:13:34.407 [TestNG-test=Package with subpackages-1] DEBUG com.github.fakemongo.impl.ExpressionParser 
12:13:34.407 [TestNG-test=Package with subpackages-1] DEBUG com.mongodb.FongoDBCollection
```

Getting huge logs for the following code (at line 3).

```
MongoCollection<Document> colls = db.getCollection("test_data");
Document criteriaDoc = (new Search(criteriaString)).getCriteria();
Document doc = colls.aggregate(Arrays.asList(Aggregates.match(criteriaDoc), Aggregates.sample(1))).first();
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what Log Implementaion you are using

Will try to generalise it.

You can set in log configuration what type of Log need to print in console and level as well like `DEGUG, INFO, WARNING` etc...

**In Spring LogBack implementation** 
logback.xml

```
<logger name="com.mongodb" level="WARNING"/>
```

**Log4J properties file**

```
props.setProperty("log4j.logger.org.mongodb.driver", "WARN");
```

**You can also do it in Java**

```
Logger mongoLogger = Logger.getLogger( "org.mongodb.driver" );
mongoLogger.setLevel(Level.WARNING);
```

Comment: I tried java code and log4j and it didn't work, I am using Log4J for logging purpose

Comment: Try with `mongoLogger.setLevel(Level.WARNING);` instead of `mongoLogger.setLevel(Level.SEVERE);`